# loading ggplot2 does not also load required packages plyr and reshape

Tags: r, ggplot2

This problem seems to have started when I updated to `R` version 2.14.2 and `ggplot2` version 0.9.0. When I load the `ggplot2` package, it does not also load `plyr` or `reshape`, so I can't use, for example `melt`. I have the packages installed, and required packages are loaded in other cases, it seems like only `ggplot2` is affected.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> cushny$SubjID <- as.factor(LETTERS[1:nrow(cushny)])
> cushny.m <- melt(cushny, id="SubjID", measure=c("Control", "drug1", "drug2L", "drug2R"), variable.name="Condition", value.name="Sleep")
Error: could not find function "melt"
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: lattice
```

Of course I can manually load the required packages, but that seems strange. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Is a new feature of ggplot and i think that it's better way to handle namespace and dependencies between packages. More info at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Namespaces

Comment: There's also this [fantastic article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-r-searches-and-finds-stuff/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/NEWS

> ggplot2 now uses a `NAMESPACE`, and only exports functions that
>   should be   user visible - this should make it play considerably more
>   nicely with other   packages in the R ecosystem. Note that this means
>   you now need to explicitly   load `plyr` (and other packages) if you
>   are using them elsewhere in your   code.

Basically, from version 0.9.0, the implementation was changed to avoid possible conflicts when multiple packages were loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how it makes ggplot2 "play more nicely with other packages". Unfortunately, I have a written a bunch of code that assumes the other packages get loaded also, so now I have to go back and fix it.